# Scala - Returning Complex type in UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've written this function:

```
def test = udf(() => List[Map[String, String]] {
  def a =  Map("A" -> "A")
  def b =  Map("B" -> "B")

  List(a, b)
})
```

And I get the following error:

> found   : List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] required: Map[String,String]
>     List(a, b)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def test = udf(() => {
  def a =  Map("A" -> "A")
  def b =  Map("B" -> "B")

  List(a, b)
})
```

aka

```
def test = udf(() => {
  def a =  Map("A" -> "A")
  def b =  Map("B" -> "B")

  List[Map[String, String]](a, b)
})
```

Comment: This works, however I am calling this function and I am expecting to get a variable of type List[Map[String, String]].

Comment: @Amaros `List(a, b)` has type `List[Map[String, String]]`.